# Alfresco: manually change the value of a node property

Tags: alfresco

I'm new to alfresco, and despite some research, I did not find how to do this basic thing : change the value of a property of a node.

It can be either via the interface or through a webscript. It is for test purposes (I display message X if node property Y has value Z), so to test I need to be able to quickly modify the property's value manually.

How do you normally do that?

Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT : I went for the OpenCMIS workbench solution suggested by skuro. However when I modify a property with it, I get the following exception :

```
Exception thrown

org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Internal Server Error

    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:450)

    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:552)

    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getObjectInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:776)

at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.getObject(ObjectServiceImpl.java:471)

at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:393)

at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:371)

at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session$getObject.call(Unknown Source)

at ConsoleScript0.run(ConsoleScript0:7)
```

Any idea what causes it?

EDIT 2 : The server logs (apparently the noderef is not correctly transmitted) :

```
14:07:47,391  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: NodeRef may not be null for calls to NodeService.  Check client code.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NodeRef may not be null for calls to NodeService.  Check client code.
        at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.getPivotNodeRef(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:319)
        at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy7.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at fr.jouve.alfresco.selex.service.cmr.impl.SelexServiceImpl.generatePlacard(SelexServiceImpl.java:514)
        at fr.jouve.alfresco.selex.repo.action.executer.selex.SelexArticleCreateUpdate.executeImpl(SelexArticleCreateUpdate.java:24)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:196)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:780)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.CompositeActionExecuter.executeImpl(CompositeActionExecuter.java:66)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:196)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:780)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:700)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:538)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:146)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy34.executeAction(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executeRule(RuleServiceImpl.java:1208)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRule(RuleServiceImpl.java:1176)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRulesImpl(RuleServiceImpl.java:1127)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRules(RuleServiceImpl.java:1100)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleTransactionListener.beforeCommit(RuleTransactionListener.java:57)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:747)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:727)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.beforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:687)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:927)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:737)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
        at org.alfresco.util.transaction.SpringAwareUserTransaction.commit(SpringAwareUserTransaction.java:472)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:403)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:436)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:466)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:304)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:351)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:188)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: which version of Alfresco are you connecting to?

Comment: that's weird, I'm running the workbench v0.5.0 against an Alfresco v3.4.0 enterprise and it's everything smooth. Do you have access to the Alfresco server logs?

Comment: That exception looks like the client side one. There should hopefully be a matching exception on the server that will tell you what went wrong, could you post that one?

Comment: I added the server-side exception.

Comment: You have a custom rule in your repository that fires on updates. This calls the SelexArticleCreateUpdate-Action which somehow tries to retrieve a property (getProperty()) with an empty nodeRef. Check your custom code or disable the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish the task. I'll show you here the ways I'd do that, which should provide some degrees of flexibility.

**Javascript + [Script Command Processor](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/URL_Addressability#Script_Command_Processor)**

Put the following Javascript file in `/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/testupdate.js`:

```
document.properties["my:property"] = "qwerty";
document.save();
```

Call the script command processor by invoking the following url:

> http://localhost:8080/alfresco/command/script/execute?scriptPath=/Company%20Home/Data%20Dictionary/Scripts/testupdate.js&contextPath=/Company%20Home/path/to/file.txt

Make sure you change URL and the context path query parameter accordingly.

**CMIS Workbench**

Download and open the [OpenCMIS workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/opencmis.html), connect to alfresco (e.g. http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis). Then in the menu click on the `Console -> - Basic Template -` item to open a groovy console. Fill in the following script (update the nodeRef to be the one of the node you want to update), then click on the "Execute Groovy Script" button:

```
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.*
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.*
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.*
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.*

// def cmis = new scripts.CMIS(session)
// println session.repositoryInfo.name
// cmis.printObjectSummary "/"
def node = session.getObject("workspace://SpacesStore/38dee96f-e028-4bed-821f-0ed25cc2ba07");
def newProps = ["cmis:name" : "qwerty"]
def oldVal = node.getProperty("cmis:name").getValue();
node.updateProperties(newProps);
def newVal = node.getProperty("cmis:name").getValue();

println oldVal + " -> " + newVal;
```

Comment: Thanks, this CMIS tool seems to be very useful. However when I try to change the property either via the property editor, or with a script such as the one you described, I get a very non-explicit exception, I added it to my question.

Comment: If you want to use the javascript way you should check out the Javascript Console in the share-extras project (shameless plug as I have written it): http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/JavascriptConsole

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that on Alfresco Explorer, you need to add the aspect that contains the properties. After that you'll find the properties textbox also on Alfresco Share.